# Where does $f(z)=z+{1\over z}$ maps the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

> $f(z)=z+{1\over z},z\in\mathbb C,z\neq 0$,then which of the following is true?
>
> $1.f$ is analytic on $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}.$
>
> $2.f$ is conformal on $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}.$.
>
> $3.f$ maps the unit circle to a subset of the real axis.
>
> $4.$ The image of any circle in $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}$ is again a circle.

$1.$ is easily seen to be true. I think $2.$ is also true because derivative of $f$ over $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}.$ is non-zero and $f$ is analytic in that region.

$3.$ is true. Because the points of the unit circle can be written as $z=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ Then ${1\over z}=(\cos\theta,-i\sin\theta).$ Hence $$f(z)=z+{1\over z}\\=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)+(\cos\theta,-i\sin\theta)\\=(\cos\theta,0).$$ So this is a subsetof the real line.I believe it is the interval $[-1,1]$ of $\mathbb R.$

$4.$ is false.Because, in similar method as $3.$,we can show that any circle under this map goes to a subset of the real line and not to any cirle.

Are my answers and corresponding methods correct$?$ Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "any circle under this map goes to a subset of the real line and not to any circle."?

Comment: @imranfat: as the unit circle goes to a subset of real line, similarly other circles will do.

Comment: Also a circle with radius 2?

Comment: @imranfat: Why? won't that be $\sqrt2 (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)?$

Comment: A point on a circle with radius 2 would be for example $2i$. This point won't be mapped onto the real axis. Just substitute to get $2i+\frac{1}{2i}$ and simplify. Just to be clear. Your answers otherwise  are correct, as Learnmore indicated. But I want to point out that circles with a radius other 1 do not map onto the real axis...

Comment: @imranfat;4 is false because it asks for any circle to satisfy the hypothesis which is false by $3$

Comment: @imranfat: But the unit circle also had the point $i.$ That got mapped to the real axis!Why won't be $2i\ ?$ $f(z)=z+\bar z$ for any $z$ as learnmore says.

Comment: @learnmore. Yes, I agree, but the OP says in part 4) "we can show that any circle under this map goes to a subset of the real line and not to any circle". No we cannot show that, because that past is not correct.

Comment: Actually, it is not true that $f'$ is never $0$. In fact, $f'(1)=0$.

Comment: @imranfat: no,I get it now. We had advantage for $|z|=1$

Comment: @user80631. The statement of Learmore after "Hence $f(z)$....is correct onder the condition that $|z|=1$, because then $|z|^2$ cancels

Comment: @imranfat: So, for other circles,or say for any other point without the modulous $1$,  $f(z)={{|z|^2\cdot z+\bar z}\over{|z|^2}}.$ Right? So, without exactly knowing the modulous, we cannot tell where the other points would go. It'll be dependant on  the $|z|^2$

Comment: Yes, that $|z|^2$ "messes" things up.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Yeah. For $z=\pm 1$ $f'(z)=0.$ So, not confirmal.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes all the arguments are correct except $2$.

Consider two unit  circles intersecting at some point in $\Bbb C$ with an angle different from $0,\pi$.

Apply $f$ on the both the circles .Since $f$ maps each circle to $\Bbb R$ so angle between them will be either $0$ or $\pi$.Hence the mapping is not conformal

For $3$ .

Hence $f(z)=z+\dfrac{1}{z}=z+\dfrac{\overline z}{|z|^2}=z+\overline z=2\text {Re} =2x$ if $z=x+iy$

Since $|z|=1$ so $x^2+y^2=1\implies x\in [-1,1]$

So $f(z)\in [-2,2]$

Comment: My argument for $2$ has been proven wrong. $f'(z)=0$ for $z=\om 1.$What now?

Comment: Sorry I had wrongly checked your derivative @user80631;I did an edit

Comment: So its not conformal then?

Comment: No ;is it not clear from the edit?

Comment: Not to me because the non-zero derivative is a sufficient citeria from what I've read till now. If it is not *necessary* then its violation may or may not mean that it's not conformal. Is not it?